# Remove <hash> tag as root from "to_xml"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to convert a hash to xml. So, I'm using `Hash.to_xml`. But, it adds as `<hash>` tag as the root

A simple example:

```
> {a: "1", b: {c: "2"}}.to_xml
```

**Gives**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<hash>
  <d>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>
      <c>2</c>
    </b>
  </d>
</hash>
```

But, I don't want the `<hash>` tag as root.

[DOC](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_xml) says, it's configurable via **root**. So, I tried

```
{d: {a: "1", b: {c: "2"}}}.to_xml(root: "")
```

But, that gives an empty `<>` instead of `<hash>`

**NOTE:** In my actual hash, I always have a root key. Like in the above example I have it as **d**. But, it's not known to me as it's dynamic

Comment: But you have to have a root tag

Comment: _"I don't want the <hash> tag as root"_ – what do you want instead?

Comment: @Stefan I updated the example I was using. So, I want the root to be `d`

Comment: @MikhailKatrin I updated the correct example

Comment: Like `{a: '1', b: {c: '2'}}.to_xml(root: 'd')`?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, you are right, the only missing fact is, I don't know the root element as it varies from different XMLs

Comment: The first hash in your example is `{a: '1', b: {c: '2'}}`, i.e. it doesn't have such "root" element.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I realised that I posted a wrong example, and I tagged you in comment saying `I updated the example I was using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Since, I always have a root key, I can do it like:

**Example**

```
hash = {d: {a: "1", b: {c: "2"}}}
root = hash.keys.first

xml = hash[root].to_xml(root: root)
```

And it will output:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<d>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>
    <c>2</c>
  </b>
</d>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look good, but

```
h = {d: {a: "1", b: {c: "2"}}}

h[h.keys.first].to_xml(root: h.keys.first)

<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<d>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>
        <c>2</c>
    </b>
</d>
```